# Combine flask form field with html input

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a FieldList form that allows users to enter in an origin and destination for routes they have travelled.

I am trying to add Google's autocomplete API to make it easier for users to enter in addresses into the fields.

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import (
  StringField,
  FormField,
  FieldList
)
from wtforms.validators import (
  Length,
  Optional
)


class RouteForm(Form):
    origin = StringField([Optional(),  Length(1, 256)])
    destination = StringField([Optional(),  Length(1, 256)])


class JourneysForm(Form):
    ids = []
    journeys = FieldList(FormField(RouteForm))
```

edit.html

```
{% import 'macros/form.html' as f with context %}

<tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for journey, route in zip(form.journeys, routes) %}
      <td>
        {% call f.location_search(journey.origin,
                            css_class='sm-margin-bottom hide-label') %}
        {% endcall %}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>


<div class="col-md-6">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      'Save'
  </button>
</div>
```

macros/forms.html

```
<head>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=<KEY>&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    
    <script>
      function initMap() {
          var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      }
    </script>
    
</head>


{# Render a form for searching a location. #}
{%- macro location_search(form, css_class='') -%}
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter location">
  {{ form(class=css_class, **kwargs) }}
  {{ caller () }}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

routes.py

```
@route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def routes_edit():

    routes = get_routes()
    journeys_form = JourneysForm()

    if journeys_form.validate_on_submit():
        for i, entry in enumerate(journeys_form.journeys.entries):

            origin = entry.data['origin']
```

However, this renders two fields. One which contains the Google autocomplete input, but does not submit the value (top). And another field which does not have the Google autocomplete input but submits the value to the db via routes.py (bottom).

[image: form]

Is it possible to combine this into a single field that both contains the Google autocomplete and submits the input value to the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WTForms actually renders an input class itself:

```
<input class="form-control" id="journeys-0-origin" name="journeys-0-origin" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
```

Therefore I was unnecessarily duplicating the input element. In order to get Google autocomplete to work I simply just had to pass the input id into my js function:

```
      function initMap() {
          var input = document.getElementById('journeys-0-origin');
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      }
```